# Replicate saveProductEntity() to save data to my custom table

Tags: magento2

How to saveProductEntity() function to save the values to my custom table.

What are the changes that are to be made?

My requirement is:

When i import the product csv, my data need to be saved to my custom table along with their product_ids.

I have tried so far: (mentioned as //custom code)

```
protected function _saveProducts()
{
    $priceIsGlobal = $this->_catalogData->isPriceGlobal();
    $productLimit = null;
    $productsQty = null;
    //custom code
    $tagmodel =  $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Queue');        
    while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {
        $entityRowsIn = [];
        $entityRowsUp = [];
        $attributes = [];
        $this->websitesCache = [];
        $this->categoriesCache = [];
        $tierPrices = [];
        $mediaGallery = [];
        $uploadedImages = [];
        $previousType = null;
        $prevAttributeSet = null;
        $existingImages = $this->getExistingImages($bunch);

        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                continue;
            }
            $rowScope = $this->getRowScope($rowData);

            $rowSku = $rowData[self::COL_SKU];

            if (null === $rowSku) {
                $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                continue;
            } elseif (self::SCOPE_STORE == $rowScope) {
                // set necessary data from SCOPE_DEFAULT row
                $rowData[self::COL_TYPE] = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['type_id'];
                $rowData['attribute_set_id'] = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['attr_set_id'];
                $rowData[self::COL_ATTR_SET] = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['attr_set_code'];
            }
            //custom code start
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/_saveProducts.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info("Product_ids: [ ".$this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['entity_id']." ] ");

            $tagProductId = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['entity_id'];
            $getId =  $tagmodel->load($tagProductId)->getEntity_id();
            if($getId=='') {                    
                $tagmodel->setEntity_id($tagProductId);
                $tagmodel->save();
            }
            //custom code end
            // 1. Entity phase
            if (isset($this->_oldSku[$rowSku])) {
                // existing row
                $entityRowsUp[] = [
                    'updated_at' => (new \DateTime())->format(DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT),
                    $this->getProductEntityLinkField()
                        => $this->_oldSku[$rowSku][$this->getProductEntityLinkField()],
                ];
            } else {
                if (!$productLimit || $productsQty < $productLimit) {
                    $entityRowsIn[$rowSku] = [
                        'attribute_set_id' => $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['attr_set_id'],
                        'type_id' => $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['type_id'],
                        'sku' => $rowSku,
                        'has_options' => isset($rowData['has_options']) ? $rowData['has_options'] : 0,
                        'created_at' => (new \DateTime())->format(DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT),
                        'updated_at' => (new \DateTime())->format(DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT),
                    ];
                    $productsQty++;
                } else {
                    $rowSku = null;
                    // sign for child rows to be skipped
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (!array_key_exists($rowSku, $this->websitesCache)) {
                $this->websitesCache[$rowSku] = [];
            }
```

My Observer has :

```
public function productUpdate($product){
    //echo 'product update';die;
    $product_id = $product->getEntityId();  //print_r($product_id);die;
    if(!$product_id) {
            return;
    }

    //$existingProduct = $this->_queue->load();
    $existingProduct->setEntity_id($product_id)
        //          ->save();

    print_r($existingProduct);die;
    /* $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Queue')->load('entity_id',$product_id);  echo '<pre>';print_r($product);die; */


}
```

Comment: I get 'Exception' with message 'Warning: Missing argument 1 for Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::load(),